# @Query doesn't work in Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, retrofit2

I have used *Retrofit* library to perform operations like `POST`,`GET` and etc.
When I use **Body** , **Query** and **Path** together in `POST` method, **Query** is ignoring by Compiler and it doesn't work!

Here is my code in my interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("video/{id}/comments/")
Call<VideoCommentsModel> videoGetCommentsModelCall(
        @Body VideoArgs videoArgs,
        @Query("page") int page,
        @Path(value = "id", encoded = true)  int id_
);
```

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

If you have *Path* and *Query* together, *path* should come before *Query* !

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("video/{id}/comments/")
Call<VideoCommentsModel> videoGetCommentsModelCall(
    @Body VideoArgs videoArgs,
    @Path(value = "id", encoded = true)  int id_,
    @Query("page") int page
);
```

Comment: Mark as answer if it solved the problem b'coz it may useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("video/{id}/comments")
Call<VideoCommentsModel> videoGetCommentsModelCall(
        @Body VideoArgs videoArgs,
        @Path(value = "id", encoded = true)  int id_,
        @Query("page") int page
);
```

Remove '/' from end of the path.

Comment: I have answered it before you but I can accept mine in at least after 2 days! thanks for your response :)